# Hangman never prints 'You won'

Tags: java, printing

Just started a computer science degree and have been tasked with making a Hangman game, it seems to work find other than it doesn't print "You won" and I cannot see/figure out why it doesn't.  Any help from you guys would be great.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rand = new Random();
    char[] alpha = new char[26];
    Arrays.fill(alpha, ' ');

    String a1 = "intro to programming";
    String a2 = "computer";
    String a3 = "mouse and keyboard";
    String a4 = "skyrim";
    String a5 = "hello world";

    int selector = rand.nextInt(5) + 1;
    char[] words = null;
    char[] show = null;

    if (selector == 1) {
        words = a1.toCharArray();
        show = a1.toCharArray();
        Arrays.fill(show, '-');
    } else if (selector == 2) {
        words = a2.toCharArray();
        show = a2.toCharArray();
        Arrays.fill(show, '-');
    } else if (selector == 3) {
        words = a3.toCharArray();
        show = a3.toCharArray();
        Arrays.fill(show, '-');
    } else if (selector == 4) {
        words = a4.toCharArray();
        show = a4.toCharArray();
        Arrays.fill(show, '-');
    } else if (selector == 5) {
        words = a5.toCharArray();
        show = a5.toCharArray();
        Arrays.fill(show, '-');
    }

    int length = words.length;
    System.out.println("Please enter the amount of tries you would like:");

    int amount = scan.nextInt();
    String guessed;
    char guessedchar;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (words[i] == ' ') {
            show[i] = ' ';
        }
    }

    int x = 0;
    while (amount >= 0) {
        System.out.print("String to guess: ");
        for (char n : show) {
            System.out.print(n);
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Number of tries left: " + amount);
        System.out.print("Number of times you have tried: ");

        for (char a : alpha) {
            System.out.print(a);
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Enter a guess");
        guessed = scan.next();
        guessedchar = guessed.charAt(0);
        alpha[x] = guessedchar;

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if (guessedchar == words[i]) {
                show[i] = guessedchar;
            }
        }

        x = x + 1;
        amount = amount - 1;
        if (amount == 0) {
            System.out.println("You lose");
            return;
        } else if (show == words) {
            System.out.println("You won");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: When do you win? Also you should learn about switch/case and increments

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should try to fix your code formatting (perhaps learn the [Google Java Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html) so it's easier for everyone else to read). Also, it would be better if you could isolate the smallest bit of code that gives you a problem (a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) rather than your whole program, which will help both you and us.

Comment: Also ask yourself what should happen when `amount != 0` and `show != words`

Comment: One problem I see in your code is, that you can't compare two char arrays with the `==` operator. So `show==words` will always return `false`.

Comment: If you are having problems then why not talk to your tutor/professor They are there to help and may be able to better point you in the correct direction.

Comment: Welcome to this community! A general hint concerning your coding style: try to avoid large methods (in your case, `main` has ~80 lines of code). Some "rules" say that a single method should have no more than 15 lines of code. By doing so and giving your methods a "speaking name" (this means that method names tell you what your method is intended to do) one can read your code much easier and hence find an error like you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the words and show arrays to Strings and check if they are equal with .equals(), this should then display the correct message